# Does anybody know why I get a java.lang.String on Stripe Payment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, stripe-payments

I have Stripe payment implemented on my android app everything is working fine.but I get an error when it comes to creating a token This is the part were I get the error

```
Stripe stripe =new  Stripe (PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
```

The error I get is `Stripe (android.content.context) in Stripe cannot be applied java.Lang.String.` to the `PUBLISHABLE_KEY` Can anybody explain to me what is happening here and how can I Fix this. My build dependencies are

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-java:3.10.1'
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
```

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android#creating-tokens-custom

Answer (score 1):

That is one of the standard Java compilation errors that you get if you try to invoke a constructor with incorrectly typed parameters.  And that is what you are doing here.

The [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android#creating-tokens-custom) explains how to obtain a `Stripe` object.

In short, you need to supply a `Context` argument; e.g.

```
Stripe stripe = new Stripe(someContext, PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
```

And the documentation says this:

> *"[A `Context`] can be the `Activity` or `Fragment` in which you are operating, or can be retrieved from any `View` via the `View#getContext()` method."*